# Optimal approach for filtering out outlier map coordinates

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, computational-geometry

I've got a list of map coordinates [lat,lon]. I would like to filter out those that by some metric, are too far away from the rest of the main group, outliers.

A) A plain approach to it would be to get the median for lat,lon and then filter out whatever is further away from that median than said metric ( e.g distance ). This would only work for an absolute distance ( e.g 5km ).

B) An improvement to that approach could be to assume that no more than x% of the coordinate pairs would be outliers (essentially setting a threshold there ). Then I'd sort the coordinates array and remove the first x/2% and the final x/2%. Then find the max distance of that group of markers which would be the distance of the first marker to the last marker in that array. Finally, apply A) with the metric for the distance being the distance we just calculated ( so that the distance metric is not fixed )

This is simply an approach I very briefly came up with so if it has any obvious downsides please let me know. In a more open discussion spirit, how would you go about solving this problem? Thanks for your input

Comment: What's wrong with the approaches you've already suggested?

Comment: Though FWIW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Detection

Comment: I dont know what i dont know. Maybe there's a better idea out there. Just checking : )

Comment: To find an "optimal" something, one needs a criterion to optimize on.

Comment: And thus i've suggested two potential metrics further down.. Could do without the downvote when this is clearly an open discussion problem

Answer (score 2):

Working separately on the coordinates is not the best approach because it is not rotation invariant.

You can try by "onion peeling", i.e. building the convex hull of the point cloud and removing the hull vertices, repeatedly.

Read the paper "Onion-Peeling Outlier Detection in 2-D data Sets; Archit Harsh, John E. Ball & Pan Wei".

Comment: Awesome, this is what i was looking for.